# Spring Boot configuration annotation not working properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am setting up a STOMP WebSocket in Spring Boot 2.7 using Java 17 & Gradle, but I'm receiving the following error when building the app:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
   ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Here is the code for WebSocket config file:

```java
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/user");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
    DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
    converter.setContentTypeResolver(resolver);
    messageConverters.add(converter);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here is my main class file:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientPortalApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ClientPortalApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

I was able to run the WebSocket using the same configuration before, but I am not able to understand why the project is giving me this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    java
    application
    `maven-publish`
    id("org.springframework.boot")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":commons"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.5")
    implementation("dev.morphia.morphia:core:1.6.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive:2.7.5")
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.6.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:2.7.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.7.5")
    implementation("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.0.4.RELEASE")
    implementation("commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4")
    implementation("com.stripe:stripe-java:21.5.0")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.7.5")
    implementation("com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.7.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
}

group = "com.project"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
description = "service"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
        from(components["java"])
    }
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile>() {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.project.clientportal.ClientPortalApplication")
}
```

Comment: @JustinBertram I am receiving this while building the app

Comment: I am using gradle. Just added the gradle module file

Comment: I'm not real familiar with Gradle, but the fact that you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException` while building indicates a problem with your Gradle configuration. Your Gradle config looks strange to me since you've listed dependencies for both `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket` **and** `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.7.0`. Then you're also declaring dependencies for `org.springframework:spring-websocket` and `org.springframework:spring-messaging` which are already included in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket`.

Comment: I have removed all of them and keep `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.7.0")` but no luck

Comment: Are you still declaring a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`? If so you should probably remove that as well because it is also included in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket`.

Comment: You should also align your versions. You're using many dependencies from `2.7.5` but then using `2.7.0` for `spring-boot-starter-websocket`.

Comment: You should also keep your question updated with everything you've tried so that other users don't have to read through all the comments to understand the current situation.

Comment: You should also eliminate all dependencies which aren't strictly required.

Comment: yes, I have removed all unnecessary dependencies and updated the edit section

Comment: You **haven't** removed all unnecessary dependencies because you are **still** declaring a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` even though it is already included in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket`. Also, your versions still aren't aligned as previously noted.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after using the following dependencies:

```
implementation("org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.22.RELEASE")
implementation("org.springframework:spring-websocket:5.2.22.RELEASE")
```

The library `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket` was creating a circular dependency that caused an error. The issue is listed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27746)